# how does scala's type check work in this case?

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching, type-inference

```
// Start writing your ScalaFiddle code here
sealed trait DSL[A]{
  // def run(): A ={
  //   this match {
  //     case GetLength(something) =>
  //       something.length
  //     case ShowResult(number) =>
  //       s"the length is $number"
  //   }
  // }
}

case class GetLength(something: String) extends DSL[Int]
case class ShowResult(number: Int) extends DSL[String]

def run[A](fa:DSL[A]): A ={
  fa match {
    case GetLength(something) =>
      something.length
    case ShowResult(number) =>
      s"the length is $number"
  }
}

val dslGetLength = GetLength("123456789")
val length = run(dslGetLength)
val dslShowResult = ShowResult(length)
println(run(dslShowResult))
// print: the length is 9
```

[scalafiddle here](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/vSXkxGA/6)

- why does the `run` function not compile in the `DSL[A]` trait, but worked outside?
- how does type inference work in this case?

Answer (score 6):

This is a case of generalized abstract data type.

When you have a `DSL[A]` and function returning `A`, compiler can prove that:

- for `case GetLength` `A=Int` so you can return `Int` there
- for `case ShowResult` `A=String` so you can return `String`

however, Scala 2 is known to not have a perfect support of GADTs, so sometimes compiler fails, even if it should work. I guess some compiler dev could figure out the exact case, but, interestingly, it can be worked around with:

```
sealed trait DSL[A]{
  def run(): A = DSL.run(this)
}
object DSL {
  def run[A](fa:DSL[A]): A ={
    fa match {
      case GetLength(something) =>
        something.length
      case ShowResult(number) =>
        s"the length is $number"
    }
  }
}

case class GetLength(something: String) extends DSL[Int]
case class ShowResult(number: Int) extends DSL[String]
```

My wild guess would be that pattern matching in a generic method is kind of a special case in a compiler, which is not triggered when `A` is fixed. I think that, because the following code also works:

```
sealed trait DSL[A]{
  def run(): A = runMe(this)
  private def runMe[B](dsl: DSL[B]): B = {
    dsl match {
      case GetLength(something) =>
        something.length
      case ShowResult(number) =>
        s"the length is $number"
    }
  }
}
```

whereas this fails as well:

```
sealed trait DSL[A]{
  def run(): A = {
    val fa: DSL[A] = this // make sure error is not related to special treatment of "this", this.type, etc
    fa match {
      case GetLength(something) =>
        something.length
      case ShowResult(number) =>
        s"the length is $number"
    }
  }
}
```

```
cmd4.sc:5: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : ammonite.$sess.cmd4.GetLength
 required: ammonite.$sess.cmd4.DSL[A]
      case GetLength(something) =>
           ^
cmd4.sc:7: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : ammonite.$sess.cmd4.ShowResult
 required: ammonite.$sess.cmd4.DSL[A]
      case ShowResult(number) =>
           ^
Compilation Failed
```

In other words, I suspect that type parameter change how things are being evaluated:

- `def runMe[B](dsl: DSL[B]): B` has a type parameter, so results of each `case` inside `match` are compared against `B` where for each case value of `B` can be proven to be some specific type (Int, String)
- in `def run: A` however compiler is somehow prevented from making such analysis - IMHO it is a bug, but perhaps it is a result of some obscure feature.

From what I see the same error occurs in Dotty, so it is either duplicated bug or a limitation of a type-level checker (after all GADT aren't widely use din Scala, yet) - I would suggest reporting issue to Scala/Dotty team and letting them decide what it is.

Answer (score 3):

Pattern matching seems to work [differently](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/DMHyBPkKcjw/Bux9TOJqWuQJ) depending on if type parameter comes from the enclosing method versus enclosing class. Here is a simplified example where using class type parameter `A`

```
trait Base[T]
case class Derived(v: Int) extends Base[Int]

class Test[A] {
  def method(arg: Base[A]) = {
    arg match {
      case Derived(_) => 42
    }
  }
}
```

raises error

```
Error:(7, 12) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : A$A87.this.Derived
 required: A$A87.this.Base[A]
      case Derived(_) => 42
           ^
```

whilst it works using method type parameter `A`

```
class Test {
  def method[A](arg: Base[A]) = {
    arg match {
      case Derived(_) => 42
    }
  }
}
```

[SLS 8.4: Pattern Matching Expressions](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-expressions) seems to explain what happens in the method scenario

> Let  be the type of the selector expression  and let 1,…, be
>   the type parameters of all methods enclosing the pattern matching
>   expression. For every , let  be its lower bound and  be
>   its higher bound. Every pattern ∈1,,…, can be typed in two
>   ways. First, it is attempted to type  with  as its expected type.
>   If this fails,  is instead typed with a modified expected type ′
>   which results from  by replacing every occurrence of a type
>   parameter  by *undefined*.

AFAIU, we have

```
e = arg
a1 = A
T = Base[A]
p1 = Derived(_)
```

First, it attempts to type  with  as its expected type, however `Derived` does not conform to `Base[A]`. Thus it attempts the second rule

> If this fails,  is instead typed with a modified expected type ′
>   which results from  by replacing every occurrence of a type
>   parameter  by *undefined*.

Assuming *undefined* means something like existential type, then we have `T' = Base[_]`, and because the following indeed holds

```
implicitly[Derived <:< Base[_]]
```

then pattern matching in the case of method type parameter becomes something like

```
class Test {
  def method[A](arg: Base[A]) = {
    (arg: Base[_]) match {
      case Derived(_) => 42
    }
  }
}
```

which indeed compiles. This seems to be confirmed by making the class type parameter case successfully compile like so

```
class Test[A] {
  def method(arg: Base[A]) = {
    (arg: Base[_]) match {
      case Derived(_) => 42
    }
  }
}
```

Therefore it seems the second rule is not attempted in [type parameter inference for constructor patterns](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#type-parameter-inference-for-constructor-patterns) when type parameter comes from enclosing class.

---

<sup>At least these seems to be some of the moving pieces which hopefully someone with actual knowledge can assemble into coherent explanation, as I am mostly guessing.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

`run` returns a generic `A`, but this only works in the case you didn't comment because you're accepting `A` as a type parameter (which the compiler can figure out).

The following would work instead:

```
sealed trait DSL[A] {
  def run(): A
}

case class GetLength(something: String) extends DSL[Int] {
  def run(): Int = something.length
}
case class ShowResult(number: Int) extends DSL[String] {
  def run(): String = s"the length is $number"
}

val dslGetLength = GetLength("123456789")
val length = dslGetLength.run()
val dslShowResult = ShowResult(length)
println(dslShowResult.run())
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/H18lYaptT366cUZBshd6QQ) or alternatively on [Scala Fiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/7orQzdl/0).

Comment: If one is pattern matching on `this`, my first instinct is to say that one has implemented a vtable. :)

Comment: Yes, things can be worked like this, just as the `run[A]` outside of the `DSL[A]` trait in my case. But I just can't figure out why this not work in the trait. I think other answers may give a clue,but thanks anyway.

Comment: Because the signature says you want the function to return an `A` but the implementation returns an `Int` in one case and a `String` in another. You're not giving the compiler enough information to figure out the relationship between those types.