# Difference between type inference of method and class type parameters in pattern matching

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-inference, type-parameter

Why does pattern matching work differently when type parameter comes from an enclosing method as opposed to an enclosing class? For example,

```
trait Base[T]
case class Derived(v: Int) extends Base[Int]

class Test[A] {
  def method(arg: Base[A]) = {
    arg match {
      case Derived(_) => 42
    }
  }
}
```

gives error

```
constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : A$A87.this.Derived
 required: A$A87.this.Base[A]
      case Derived(_) => 42
           ^
```

whilst it successfully compiles when `A` is method type parameter

```
class Test {
  def method[A](arg: Base[A]) = {
    arg match {
      case Derived(_) => 42
    }
  }
}
```

---

<sup>The question is based on Daniel's [analysis](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/DMHyBPkKcjw/Bux9TOJqWuQJ), which I used to attempt to provide [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60553882/5205022) to similar question.</sup>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have the 100% complete answer, but I have a pointer that might be sufficient for you.

Scala compiler deals with GADTs (Generalized Algebraic Data Types) in a very particular way. Some cases are solved with special handling, some cases are unsolved. Dotty is trying to fill most of the holes, and it has already [solved](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues?q=is%3Aissue+gadt+is%3Aclosed) a lot of related issues, however there are still quite a few [open](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues?q=is%3Aissue+gadt+is%3Aopen) ones as well.

Typical example of special GADT handling in Scala 2 compiler is very related to your use case. If we take a look at:

```
def method[A](arg: Base[A]) = {
  arg match {
    case Derived(_) => 42
  }
}
```

and we explicitly declare the return type to be `A`:

```
def method[A](arg: Base[A]): A
```

it will compile just fine. Your IDE might complain, but the compiler will let it through. Method says it returns an `A`, but the pattern matching case evaluates into an `Int`, which theoretically shouldn't compile. However, special handling of GADTs in the compiler says it's fine, because in that particular pattern matching branch `A` has been "fixed" to be an `Int` (because we matched on `Derived` which is a `Base[Int]`).

Generic type parameter for the GADT (in our case `A`) has to be declared somewhere. And here's the interesting part - special compiler handling **only works when it's declared as the type parameter of the enclosing method**. If it's coming from a type member or a type parameter of the enclosing trait/class, it doesn't compile, as you witnessed yourself.

This is why I said it's not a 100% complete answer - I cannot point to a concrete place (such as official specification) which documents this properly. Sources on handling of GADTs in Scala come down to a [couple](https://gist.github.com/smarter/2e1c564c83bae58c65b4f3f041bfb15f) [of](https://github.com/chrilves/gadt.scala) [blogposts](https://pchiusano.github.io/2014-05-20/scala-gadts.html), which are great by the way, but if you want more than that you will have to dig into the compiler code yourself. I tried doing exactly that, and I think it comes down to [this method](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/284a9c03c650c76e2b5295fee5c03565bcdf5246/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Infer.scala#L1089-L1121), but if you really want to go deeper, you might want to ping someone more experienced with the Scala compiler codebase.